# Python: How do you join a list and a text wrap at the same time

Tags: python, join, word-wrap

I am trying to print all the items in a list named `CND_Info`, which is made from a dictionary called `Index_Lookup_Conditions`. I want to print each item of the list on its own line beginning with an "~" but also textwrap it to 80 characters. Here is the code so far:

```
PROG = str(input("Type condition name: "))
for key, value in Index_Lookup_Conditions.items():
    if (key == PROG):
        print(key + "\n")
        CND_Info = value.split("|")
        print("~" + "\n~".join(CND_Info))
```

I could possibly make a loop for each item in `CND_Info` to textwrap it but was wondering if there is a simpler way.

Comment: protip: `print('~', *CND_Info, sep='\n~')`

Comment: if a line is broken at the 80th character, should both resulting lines start with `~`, or just the first line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`textwrap.fill`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.fill) for this:

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> lst = [c*20 for c in 'abcdef']
>>> print '\n'.join('~' + textwrap.fill(x, 15) for x in lst)
~aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaa
~bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbb
~ccccccccccccccc
ccccc
~ddddddddddddddd
ddddd
~eeeeeeeeeeeeeee
eeeee
~fffffffffffffff
fffff
```

Using `print()` function(Python 3):

```
>>> print(*('~' + textwrap.fill(x, 15) for x in lst), sep='\n')
~aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaa
~bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbb
~ccccccccccccccc
ccccc
~ddddddddddddddd
ddddd
~eeeeeeeeeeeeeee
eeeee
~fffffffffffffff
fffff
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from textwrap import fill

CND_Info = ['Some text line',
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. '
            'Praesent nisi leo, interdum vel nulla vitae, mollis rutrum velit.']

for line in CND_Info:
    print fill('~' + line, 80)
```